# React не перерендеривает после изменения состояния

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

Использую состояния в связке с контекстом для работы с данными "todo", храню все данные в одном классе для удобства (сам класс работает проверял все выводы через логи), но вот после изменеия не срабатывает setState

App

```
function App() {
  
  const [todoList, settodoList] = useState(new TODOList)
  todoList.UpcomingTasks.GenerateTestData()
  todoList.Remove(1)


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DataContext.Provider  value={{todoList, settodoList}} >
        {/* <AddTaskModal/> */}
        <Head />
        <Body />
      </DataContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Body

```
const Body = function () {
    
    return (
      <div className={style.Body}>
          <strong>All Task</strong>
          <TodoList/>
      </div>
    )
}
```

List

```
const TodoList = function () {

    if (todoList.UpcomingTasks.data.length) {
        return(
            <div>
              {todoList.UpcomingTasks.data.map(todo =>  {return <TodoItem todoItem={todo} key={todo.id}/>}  )}
            </div>
        )
    }
    else
    {
        return <div><strong>No assignments upcoming, it looks like it's time to rest</strong></div>
    }
}
```

Item

```
    const TodoItem = function ({todoItem}) {
    
        const {todoList, settodoList} = useData()
    
        return (
            <div className={style.Item}>
                <div className={style.LeftBlock}>
                    {/* <button class={style.Checkbox} onClick={() => { dataTodoList.ToggleToDo(id = todoItem.id, upcoming = true) }}></button> */}
                    <span className={style.TodoTitle}>{todoItem.title}</span>
                </div>

                //По клику на данную кнопку должно происходить удаление задачи, 
                //заддача удаляется из класса, но не происходит изменения состояния и она 
                //продолжает отображаться, хотя в массиве задач ее уже нет 
                <button className={style.Delite} onClick={() => {todoList.Remove(todoItem.id); settodoList(todoList);  console.log("Removed"); console.log(todoList)}}>
                    <img src={trash} alt="" />
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Ps: useData <=> useContext(DataContext),
Изучаю React и js недавно, буду рад любой помощи, заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вы не изменяете стейт.
Вы создаете экземпляр класса `TODOList`, передаете в провайдер ссылку на этот экземпляр, что-то в нем меняете и в `settodoList` передаете ссылку на этот же экземпляр. Фактически для реакта ничего не меняется, т.к. в стейте находилась ссылка именно на этот же экземпляр.

Передавайте в `settodoList` новый экземпляр класса.